# Unable to install pyaudio in a python 3.9.1 virtual environnement in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, python, aptitude

I'm kindly asking for your help. I'm trying to install `pyaudio` in a python virtual environment version 3.9.1 on Ubuntu 20.04 but I get this error when I run `pip install pyaudio` in my venv:

> error: subprocess-exited-with-error
> × Building wheel for pyaudio (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.   │ exit code: 1   ╰─> [18 lines of output]
> running bdist_wheel
> running build
> running build_py
> creating build
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
> creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
> copying src/pyaudio/**init**.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/pyaudio
> running build_ext
> building 'pyaudio._portaudio' extension
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src
> creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio
> gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include -I/home/fany/Documents/a_soro/rep_travail/venv/include -I/home/fany/.pyenv/versions/3.9.1/include/python3.9 -c src/pyaudio/device_api.c -o
> build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-39/src/pyaudio/device_api.o
> src/pyaudio/device_api.c:9:10: fatal error: portaudio.h: No such file or directory
> 9 | #include "portaudio.h"
> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
> compilation terminated.
> error: command '/usr/bin/gcc' failed with exit code 1
> [end of output]
> note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.   ERROR: Failed building wheel for pyaudio ERROR:
> Could not build wheels for pyaudio, which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects
> I found that I need `portaudio19-dev` so I try to install it with apt first but it didn't give info about the dependencies conflicts so I tried `sudo aptitude install portaudio19-dev` and it give me this:
>
> The following NEW packages will be installed:   libasound2-dev{ab}
> libjack-dev{a} libjack0{ab} libportaudiocpp0{a} portaudio19-dev  0
> packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> Need to get 526 kB of archives. After unpacking 4,108 kB will be used.
> The following packages have unmet dependencies:  libjack-jackd2-0 :
> Conflicts: libjack-0.116 which is a virtual package, provided by:
> - libjack0 (1:0.125.0-3build2), but 1:0.125.0-3build2 is to be installed
> - libjack-jackd2-0 (1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2), but 1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2 is installed
>
> ```
>                 Conflicts: libjack-0.125 which is a virtual package, provided by:
>                            - libjack0 (1:0.125.0-3build2), but 1:0.125.0-3build2 is to be installed
>                            - libjack-jackd2-0 (1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2), but 1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2 is installed
>
>                 Conflicts: libjack0 but 1:0.125.0-3build2 is to be installed  libasound2-dev : Depends: libasound2 (= 1.2.2-2.1) but
> ```
>
> 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu2.2 is installed  libjack0 : Conflicts: libjack-0.116 which is a virtual package, provided by:
> - libjack0 (1:0.125.0-3build2), but 1:0.125.0-3build2 is to be installed
> - libjack-jackd2-0 (1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2), but 1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2 is installed
>
> ```
>         Conflicts: libjack-0.125 which is a virtual package, provided by:
>                    - libjack0 (1:0.125.0-3build2), but 1:0.125.0-3build2 is to be installed
>                    - libjack-jackd2-0 (1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2), but 1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2 is installed The following actions will resolve these dependencies:
>
>  Remove the following packages:                         1)     libjack-jackd2-0 [1.9.12~dfsg-2ubuntu2 (focal, now)]
>
>  Keep the following packages at their current version:  2)     libasound2-dev [Not Installed]                       3)
> ```
>
> portaudio19-dev [Not Installed]

I don't know what to do from that point because in the past I remove or downgrade some packages and it results in a big problem in my OS.So this time I think it is safe to ask you first in case you had a similar issue with pyaudio the options that you choose in the suggestions of aptitude. How can I deal with this issue and be able to install pyaudio in my virtual environment.